# is there any function or module in nlp that would find a specific paragraph headings

Tags: python, machine-learning, nlp, data-science, information-extraction

I have a text file . I need to identify specific paragraph headings and if true i need to extract relevant tables and paragraph wrt that heading using python.  can we do this by nlp or machine learning?. if so please help me out in gathering basics as i am new to this field.I was thinking of using a rule like:

if (capitalized) and heading_length <50:
    return heading_text

how do i parse through the entire document and pick  only the header names ? this is like automating human intervention of clicking document,scrolling to relevant subject and picking it up.

please help me out in this

Answer (score 1):

You probably don't need NLP or machine learning to detect these headings. Figure out the rule you actually want and if indeed it is such a simple rule as the one you wrote, a regexp will be sufficient. If your text is formatted (e.g. using HTML) it might be even simpler.

If however, you can't find a rule, and your text isn't really formatted consistently, your problem will be hard to solve.

Comment: thanks for initial help ..i tried out below using beautiful soup : `import mammoth
with open(r"D:\Users\1202584\source\2018 09 18 MA Benefit Specification FINAL.docx", "rb") as docx_file:
    result = mammoth.convert_to_html(docx_file)
    html = result.value`  after converting to html format i pulled out the only headers using below code `soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html5lib') 
for heading in soup.find_all(["h1"]):
    if heading.text.strip():
        header_names=print(heading.text.strip())`          now my next challenge is how do i fetch the above header tables ?

Comment: Please consider using a dedicated package for parsing docx files instead of trying to parse them as HTML or XML, e.g. python-docx. Once you unwrap the docx your work will be much easier.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with lorg. Although you could use NLP, but that might just complicate the problem. This problem could be an optimization problem if performance is a concern.